# audio video photo path and access method

Tags: iphone

I hope to know what is the absolute path of storing audio, video and photos.
Are they in a same path?

I know I can use UIImagePicker to access saved photo.
Are there standard sdk/frame to access audio video?
or I need to construct the codes by myself?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: in iOS 4.0, the [`ALAssetsLibrary`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API will let you access media directly.

Comment: Thanks, can it support low version ipod/iphone?